# Record Type picklist on page layout

Tags: force.com, page-layout, record-type

I have a custom object having 2 record types. Instead of having to select the record type (on the first screen) before creating the actual record, I want to have it as a drop down on the main page.
Where can use can select the record type like any other picklist field.

Is this possible?

Comment: Recordtypes are assigned to different page layouts. That why its selection has own page. Of course you could create custom VF page. But what is the point

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you need by using only the standard layouts. Because the Record Type determines what Page Layout is shown, standard Salesforce functionality is to ask for it before presenting the user with the detailed screen.

You can do a couple of things to mitigate this:

1) Create Custom Buttons (and place them on a related list, for example) that know what RT will be used and pass the ID to the page as a parameter, then the page will already be selected

2) Code your way around this, by writing VF to do this for you... I am not sure this is the solution I'd choose, but it is there.